# Give space from bottom to graph in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I am using this code to draw two plots in one figure but I can't figure out how to give space from bottom to graph.

```
def visualize_trends(df, features, titles, fig_title, fn, vs = 0.18, h = 1000, w = 800):

    trace0 = go.Scatter(
        x = df[features[0]],
        y = df['Past_Developers_Count'],
        mode = 'lines+markers',
        name = 'Past',
    )

    trace1 = go.Scatter(
        x = df[features[1]],
        y = df['Future_Developers_Count'],
        mode = 'lines+markers',
        name = 'Future',
    )

    fig = tools.make_subplots(rows = 2, cols = 1, vertical_spacing = vs, subplot_titles = titles)

    fig.append_trace(trace0, 1, 1)
    fig.append_trace(trace1, 2, 1)

    fig['layout'].update(height = h, width = w, paper_bgcolor = 'rgb(233,233,233)', title = fig_title)

    py.iplot(fig, filename = fn)
```

Output:

[image]

Is there any parameter for giving space as I used `vertical_spacing` to give space between two graphs?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself. You can give `margin` to give required space. In `margin`, you can specify space from all sides `left, right, bottom, up`.

```
margin = dict(l = 10, r = 20, b = 30, u = 40)
```

You can pass values according to your own requirements. I did like this in my case to give space from bottom,

```
margin = dict(b = 140)
```

Complete function,

```
def visualize_trends(df, features, titles, fig_title, fn, vs = 0.18, h = 1000, w = 800):

    trace0 = go.Scatter(
        x = df[features[0]],
        y = df['Past_Developers_Count'],
        mode = 'lines+markers',
        name = 'Past',
    )

    trace1 = go.Scatter(
        x = df[features[1]],
        y = df['Future_Developers_Count'],
        mode = 'lines+markers',
        name = 'Future',
    )

    fig = tools.make_subplots(rows = 2, cols = 1, vertical_spacing = vs, subplot_titles = titles)

    fig.append_trace(trace0, 1, 1)
    fig.append_trace(trace1, 2, 1)

    fig['layout'].update(height = h, width = w, margin = dict(b = 140), 
                         paper_bgcolor = 'rgb(233,233,233)', title = fig_title)

    py.iplot(fig, filename = fn)
```

Output:

[image]

Note: I am posting this answer so someone can save their time on this issue.